# How ansible sets variables ('required_pkgs')?

Tags: ansible

I'm working on Kubespray 2.16

At `roles/kubernetes/preinstall/tasks/0070-system-packages.yml`, there is a task "Install packages requirements"

```yaml
- name: Install packages requirements
  package:
    name: "{{ required_pkgs | default([]) | union(common_required_pkgs|default([])) }}"
    state: present
  register: pkgs_task_result
  until: pkgs_task_result is succeeded
  retries: "{{ pkg_install_retries }}"
  delay: "{{ retry_stagger | random + 3 }}"
  when: not (ansible_os_family in ["Flatcar Container Linux by Kinvolk", "ClearLinux"] or is_fedora_coreos)
  tags:
    - bootstrap-os
```

According to the code, the package `{{ required_pkgs | default([]) | union(common_required_pkgs|default([])) }}` will be installed.

And I found the required_pkgs in `roles/kubernetes/preinstall/vars/*.yml`

In `redhat.yml`,

```yaml
required_pkgs:
  - "{{ ( (ansible_distribution_major_version | int) < 8) | ternary('libselinux-python','python3-libselinux') }}"
  - device-mapper-libs
  - nss
  - conntrack
```

In `centos.yml`,

```yaml
required_pkgs:
  - "{{ ( (ansible_distribution_major_version | int) < 8) | ternary('libselinux-python','python3-libselinux') }}"
  - device-mapper-libs
  - nss
  - conntrack
```

I think there is no process for Ansible to check my OS in "this task". Then how the Ansible set `required_pkgs` among a lot of YML files?

p.s. My OS is RedHat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, when Ansible first starts executing a play it will implicitly run the [setup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/setup_module.html) module on all the remote hosts involved in the play. This is called the "fact gathering" step, and is controlled by the `gather_facts` option in the play or the `gathering` option in `ansible.cfg`.

The facts gathered in this step include things like operating system flavor, release, information about interfaces and disks, and a variety of other host metadata. The variables are all all in the `ansible_*` namespace (e.g., `ansible_distribution_major_version`).

Kubespray is taking advantage of these automatically gathered facts to load the appropriate vars files.

For more information:

- [Discovering variables: facts and magic variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html) (from the Ansible documentation)
- [An introduction to Ansible facts](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/playing-ansible-facts)

Etc.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got to know how the ansible gets the information of remote host.
What if I change the name of file "redhat.yaml" to "HI.yaml"?
Then the task "Install packages requirements" will fail?

Comment: I would expect it to, yes, but the easiest way to answer that question is to try it and find out!

Comment: I will try thanks!