# How to get date and time from Remote Server and use it on a task running on Ansible Control Node?

Tags: datetime, ansible, ansible-facts

As my Ansible Control Node time is in UTC, I want to get the date and time from a Windows Remote Server, `10.14.2.130`, and use that date and time for a file name.

`10.14.2.130` is already in my inventory file.

My playbook:

```yaml
- name: Rename file with local date and time
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

    - name: Rename file
      delegate_to: 10.14.2.130
      delegate_facts: true
      become: yes
      copy:
        src: /var/lib/awx/projects/Windows/{{ createfilename }}
        dest: /var/lib/awx/projects/Windows/{{ date_time }}{{ createfilename }}
      vars:
        date_time: "{{ date }}_{{ hms }}"
        date: "{{ '%d-%m-%Y' | strftime(hostvars['10.14.2.130'].ansible_date_time.epoch) }}"
        hms: "{{ '%H.%M.%S' | strftime(hostvars['10.14.2.130'].ansible_date_time.epoch) }}"
```

Error msg:

```json
"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: {{ date }}_{{ hms }}: {{ '%d-%m-%Y' | strftime(hostvars['10.14.2.130'].ansible_date_time.epoch) }}: 'ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVarsVars object' has no attribute 'ansible_date_time'\n"
}
```

From the error message, it looks like I need to define the `ansible_date_time` variable for `10.14.2.130`?

How and where do I do it?

Comment: You don’t need to define it. But since it is a host fact and you asked for no facts `gather_facts: false`, it is not define in that playbook.

Comment: I just tried gather_facts: true, and still got the exact same error

Answer (score 1):

> *I want to get ... date and time from a Windows Remote Node ...*

In order to do so you'll need to [`gather_facts`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#ansible-facts) from the specific Remote Node.

**`hosts.ini`**

```ini
[test]
test.example.com
```

A [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Gather date and time only
    setup:
      gather_subset:
        - 'date_time'
        - '!min'

  - name: Show Gathered Facts
    debug:
      msg: "{{ hostvars['test.example.com'] }}"

  - name: Show 'date_time' from specific Remote Node only
    debug:
      msg: "{{ hostvars['test.example.com'].ansible_facts.date_time }}"
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Show 'date_time' from specific Remote Node only] ******
ok: [test.example.com] =>
  msg:
    date: '2023-07-17'
    day: '17'
    epoch: '1689595200'
    hour: '14'
    iso8601: '2023-07-17T12:00:00Z'
    iso8601_basic: 20230717T140000000000
    iso8601_basic_short: 20230717T140000
    iso8601_micro: '2023-07-17T12:00:00.000000Z'
    minute: '06'
    month: '07'
    second: '00'
    time: '14:00:00'
    tz: CEST
    tz_dst: CEST
    tz_offset: '+0200'
    weekday: Monday
    weekday_number: '1'
    weeknumber: '29'
    year: '2023'
```

since the `debug` module is executed on the Control Node (`localhost`) only already by design.

Or even possible

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Gather date and time only
    delegate_to: test.example.com
    setup:
      gather_subset:
        - 'date_time'
        - '!min'

  - name: Show Gathered Facts
    debug:
      msg: "{{ hostvars['test.example.com'] }}"

  - name: Show 'date_time' from specific Remote Node only
    debug:
      msg: "{{ hostvars['test.example.com'].ansible_facts.date_time }}"
```

**Similar Q&A**

- [How to gather `ansible_facts` ... only when needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73470572/6771046)

**Further Reading**

- [How Ansible `gather_facts` and sets variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71043335/6771046)
- [What is the exact list of Ansible `setup` `min`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71061125/6771046)
- [Playbook execution](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_intro.html#playbook-execution)

  > *Playbooks with multiple 'plays' can orchestrate multi-machine deployments, running one play on your webservers, then another play on your database servers, then a third play on your network infrastructure, and so on.*